# I need help converting Perl's "unpack" code to Python code

Tags: python, perl, binary

I'm trying to build a Python program that does the exact same thing as a Perl program. I know that Python has an unpack function like Perl but I can't figure out the format.

**Perl code**:

```
open(TSK_FILE,"<$tsk_file_name") or die("Failed to open $tsk_file_name\n");
binmode TSK_FILE;
$all = do { local $/; <TSK_FILE> };
close(TSK_FILE);

$temp_str = unpack("A20",$all); # I want to cover these two lines
print(" Operator Name : $temp_str\n");
```

**Python code**:

```
try:
    with open(tsk_file_name, 'rb')as TSK_File:
        all = TSK_File.read()
    print(all)
except IOError:
    print('There was an error opening the file!')
    return

temp_str = struct.unpack('c', ) # I got stuck here
```

---

**Edit**:

**Perl documentation for unpack**: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_unpack.htm

"This function unpacks the binary string STRING using the format specified in TEMPLATE."

Format: `unpack TEMPLATE, STRING`

**Python documentation for unpack**: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Image from: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-python-struct-module

[image]

---

**Edit 2**

When I read the binary file with f.read(), this is what prints out.

[image]

Comment: Would save the reader some work if you could describe what the Perl "unpack" does here.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you Michael for bringing that up. I added some links and short description of what "unpack" does. Let me know if I should add more detail.

Comment: `$temp_str = unpack("A20",$all)` sets $temp_str to the first 20 ascii characters in $all and strips any trailing spaces if there are spaces to the end of the 20 chars..

Comment: how was your file written?  any chance to see a hexdump of a typical line?

Comment: @zdim I have printed out the content of the file and a snippet of it has been posted into the question statement above.

Comment: hm.  Unless `.read` does something particular, it appears that you have null-padded records -- if so you'd unpack with `unpack("a20", $v)` (low-case `a`).  The `"A20"` is for space-padded ones. It may work just fine anyway since null bytes may not hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl the template `A20` means "20-character space-padded ASCII string." The nearest Python analog is `20s`. (The `c` format is for single characters, not strings.) You want:

```
temp_str = struct.unpack('20s', all)
```

That said, pack/unpack are for binary data; your example looks like the file is really text. If that's the case, it would be simpler to read it as text and avoid unpacking altogether.

Comment: @Michael Carman I got the following error when I entered your code:

    temp_str = struct.unpack('20s', all)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 20 bytes

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael, looks like you're dealing with text data, if that's the case you can just pull out the two lines like so:

```
with open(tsk_file_name, 'r')as tsk_file:
    first_line = next(tsk_file)
    second_line = next(tsk_file)
```

Comment: I have added an image in the question statement above.